# Use the focusMode constraint to get required media device

Tags: javascript, android, camera, chromium, brave

**Hello everybody!**

Currently, I'm working on the implementation of a qr-code scanner for my web application. After some tests on multiple devices, I've noticed that I have to set the focusMode constraint to get a camera that has the ability to auto-focus the environment.

I'm able to directly select the camera on my debug device by directly setting the deviceId in the constraints like this:

```
let stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
    video: {
        deviceId: "332d34c91861f97ba8f0e11f446da4566a1803539764dd67c1dfe036ef32fd97"
    }
});
```

Which I can call `stream.getVideoTracks()[0].getCapabilities()` on to get the capabilities.

```
{
    aspectRatio: {max: 4000, min: 0.0003333333333333333},
    colorTemperature: {max: 7000, min: 2850, step: 50},
    deviceId: "332d34c91861f97ba8f0e11f446da4566a1803539764dd67c1dfe036ef32fd97",
    exposureCompensation: {max: 2, min: -2, step: 0.10000000149011612},
    exposureMode: (2) ["continuous", "manual"],
    exposureTime: {max: 1250, min: 0, step: 0},
    facingMode: ["environment"],
    focusMode: (3) ["manual", "single-shot", "continuous"],
    frameRate: {max: 30, min: 0},
    groupId: "40f2953f5fae495c7471348c844e919762a3213019b271664d220d0aa617313c",
    height: {max: 3000, min: 1},
    iso: {max: 4000, min: 20, step: 1},
    resizeMode: (2) ["none", "crop-and-scale"],
    torch: true,
    whiteBalanceMode: (2) ["continuous", "manual"],
    width: {max: 4000, min: 1}
}
```

> Copied from the Chromium console log.

So I tried the following constraints via *Brave* (based on Chromium) remote debugging on my Samsung Galaxy A51, of which none worked:

```
let stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
    video: {
        focusMode: {exact: ["continuous"]}
    }
});


let stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
    video: {
        focusMode: "continuous"
    }
});


let stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
    video: {
        focusMode: ["continuous"]
    }
});


let stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
    video: {
        advanced: [{focusMode: "continuous"}]
    }
});


let stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
    video: {
        advanced: [{focusMode: ["continuous"]}]
    }
});


let stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
    video: {
        advanced: [{focusMode: {exact: "continuous"}}]
    }
});
```

I don't know if the structure is correct and I'm not quite sure how to find that out.

*Does anybody know how to use the `focusMode` constraint to get a device that has a continuous focus mode?*

Comment: Update: Also tested the implementation in Google Chrome which ended up in the same situation.

Comment: I am facing the same issue here on One Plus. It seems there is support in both the browser and the MediaTrack.  What do you see if you use `track.getConstraints()` ?

Comment: Always an empty object. It seems like Chromium doesn't recognize the constraint even though it is declared as supported. 
I've created [this issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1243275&q=focusMode&can=2) for the Chromium project, but I haven't got a useful response yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the: [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Media_Streams_API/Constraints)

> The process works like this (using MediaStreamTrack as an example):
>
> 1. If needed, call MediaDevices.getSupportedConstraints() to get the
>    list of supported constraints, which tells you what constrainable
>    properties the browser knows about. This isn't always necessary,
>    since any that aren't known will be ignored when you specify
>    them—but if you have any that you can't get by without, you can
>    start by checking to be sure they're on the list.
> 2. Once the script knows whether the property or properties it wishes to use are supported, it can then check the capabilities of the API
>    and its implementation by examining the object returned  the track's
>    getCapabilities() method; this object lists each supported constraint
>    and the values or range of values which are supported.
> 3. Finally, the track's applyConstraints() method is called to configure the API as desired by specifying the values or ranges of
>    values it wishes to use for any of the constrainable properties about
>    which it has a preference.
> 4. The track's getConstraints() method returns the set of constraints passed into the most recent call to applyConstraints().This may not
>    represent the actual current state of the track, due to properties
>    whose requested values had to be adjusted and because platform default
>    values aren't represented. For a complete representation of the
>    track's current configuration, use getSettings().
>
> In the Media Stream API, both MediaStream and MediaStreamTrack have
> constrainable properties.

Probably your `focusMode` is a default setting, that your phone figures out for himself. So you have to use getSettings() to return the actual value.

What is `.getSettings()` returning ?

Comment: .getSettings() does indeed return the correct constraints. Thank you for the answer!

I don't think this is good behaviour, but at least this documentation explains why the things are the way they are.